# The lyrics of the song by a Greek band Fade -- No Trust

Tags: lyrics

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEnE1bKo-Lg) is the music video for the song by a Greek band Fade -- No Trust. Unfortunately, not all the words are legible (I'm not a native English speaker) and I didn't manage to Google the lyrics for this song. Here is what I managed to hear:

> I feel so strange,
>
> I've seen the way out, I've seen the way out,
>
> I've got nothing to say,
>
> Everything seems full, everything seems full.
>
> ????
>
> I want a way out, I want a way out,
>
> Your lips are away,
>
> Nobody calls me, nobody calls me.
>
> I feel alone,
>
> I see you turn around, I see you turn around,
>
> ????
>
> I need you helpless, I need you helpless.
>
> ????
>
> There's nothing to give me, there's nothing to give me,
>
> Your lips are away,
>
> Nobody calls me, nobody calls me.
>
> I will never trust you again,
>
> Wish a place to hide away,
>
> I will never trust you again,
>
> Wish a place to hide away.
>
> I feel alone,
>
> I see you turn around, I see you turn around,
>
> ????
>
> I need you helpless, I need you helpless.
>
> ????
>
> There's nothing to give me, there's nothing to give me,
>
> Your lips are away,
>
> Nobody calls me, nobody calls me.
>
> I will never trust you again,
>
> Wish a place to hide away,
>
> I will never trust you again,
>
> Wish a place to hide away, away.

I can't understand the lines marked with '????' signs and I'm not sure about the line 'Everything seems full, everything seems full'. I would be grateful if you could help me with these lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are what I believe to be the correct lyrics. This song has some parts that are definitely hard to understand. The lead singer mumbles many of the lyrics.

I feel so strange,

I see no way out, I see no way out,

I've got nothing to say,

Everything seems full, everything seems full.

Our world is away,

I want a way out, I want a way out,

Our lips are away,

Nobody calls me, nobody calls me.

I feel alone,

I see you turn around, I see you turn around,

Do a circle for me,

I need you helpless, I need you helpless.

Our world is full,

There's nothing to give me, there's nothing to give me,

Your lips are away,

Nobody calls me, nobody calls me.

I will never trust you again,

Wish a place to hide away,

I will never trust you again,

Wish a place to hide away.

I feel alone,

I see you turn around, I see you turn around,

Do a circle for me,

I need you helpless, I need you helpless.

Our world is full,

There's nothing to give me, there's nothing to give me,

Your lips are away,

Nobody calls me, nobody calls me.

I will never trust you again,

Wish a place to hide away,

I will never trust you again,

Wish a place to hide away, away.